# How to Inherit Classes conditionally in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not sure whether is this possible for not but I have a requirement that needs to inherit classes conditionally.

For example I have a class Name ABC need to Inherit PQR sometime and XYZ conditionally like

```
Public Class ABC : PQR OR Public Class ABC:XYZ
```

So I want to do like with help of web.config app setting if we require Old Config inherit PQR else inherit XYZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really how inheritance is designed to work. The way to do this is through composition or factory classes.

Either way you define an interface or abstract class that PQR and XYZ both implement.

Option 1, composition: Have your class contain a member that is of the type of that interface or abstract class and then use the config to decide which concrete class to assign to that member.

Option 2, factory: Have a factory class that makes these objects on demand and grabs the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two different classes ABC1 and ABC2 but you can make them implement the same interface (IAbc).

Then you can use the interface in the places of your code you normally use ABC.

You won't be able to create instances of that classes directly but you can relay on a Factory class or your IoC container for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use main window as a user control, if you have stand-alone version of your control for instance.   This is how I conditionally build as a window or usercontrol

## if STANDALONE

```
public class MyUserControl : Window
{
}
```

## else

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
}
```

## endif